# Define a topic for a Plot in a rqt_gui perspective

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a perspective in rqt_gui with several Plot plugins. However, each time I open the perspective, all the Plot plugins appear in its correct position but the topic they have to plot is not stored. There is a way to set the topics and avoid to define them every time?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55618/define-a-topic-for-a-plot-in-a-rqt_gui-perspective/) by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi narcispr,

if you launch rqt_gui when not all topics are being published yet, the plugins that depend on a topic will require you to set that topic again, but if you launch rqt_gui at the end, when everything is published, then your saved setup will keep track of the same topics.

1. First, open all nodes and rqt_gui
   and set it up as you like.
2. Then, close rqt_gui first, then all nodes.
3. When you need to work again, run
   first all nodes, then rqt_gui.

That works for me.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2013-02-19**:
Not for me Miquel :( Maybe because I'm still running fuerte. Thank you!